# Usage of cvlc with coproc

Tags: bash, vlc, coprocesses, cvlc

I'm trying to feed to file descriptor `.mp3` files the with the dummy interface of `vlc`, i.e., `cvlc`, in order to add to a playlist on the fly or override the entire file descriptor with new data (new `.mp3` file):

```
coproc cvlc
cvlc filename.mp3 >& OR >>&"${COPROC[1]}"
```

This will run but will wait for the prompt to back which is not expected since its directing output to file descriptor.